# Multiple Dependent Comboboxes Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

[Four Comboboxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9npN.png)

I have four comboboxes. I initialize the first one with

```
Fill DC1ComboBox
With DC1
    .AddItem "Door Open/Close"
    .AddItem "Jacket On/Off"
    .AddItem "Cycle Over"
    .AddItem "Alarm"
    .AddItem "Keycard Reader"
End With
```

The second combobox options depend on the the first selection, which I did with Select Case based off of the DC1.ListIndex and that works fine.

I've started on the 3rd combobox (which depends on the second, which depends on the first) and I'm thinking there has to be a better way than how I'm nesting the select cases because it's just going to be stupidly long by the time I get to the 4th box.

For what I'm trying to do Jacket, Cycle, and Alarm can only be selected once out of the four boxes, Door and Keycard can be selected twice. Example: [Dry Contact 3 Selection Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BTv5.png)

And here is a clip of the nested select case I had started: [Nested Select Case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5ENR.png)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using cases, it's probably easier to increment variables each time a certain option is selected, and then check how many times that option has been selected. The sub below is for ComboBox #1, and you can use similar subs for #2 and #3.

```
Public jacket As Integer
Public alarm As Integer
Public cycle As Integer
Public door As Integer
Public keycard As Integer

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

'check value of combobox and increment variables
If ComboBox1.Value = "Jacket On/Off" And lastValue <> ComboBox1.Value Then
    jacket = jacket + 1
End If

If ComboBox1.Value = "Cycle Over" And lastValue <> ComboBox1.Value Then
    cycle = cycle + 1
End If

If ComboBox1.Value = "Alarm" And lastValue <> ComboBox1.Value Then
    alarm = alarm + 1
End If

If ComboBox1.Value = "Keycard Reader" And lastValue <> ComboBox1.Value Then
    keycard = keycard + 1
End If

    If ComboBox1.Value = "Door Open/Close" And lastValue <> ComboBox1.Value Then
    door = door + 1
End If

'check totals of variables and add correct items
With ComboBox2

    .clear

    If jacket < 1 Then
    .AddItem "Jacket On/Off"
    End If

    If cycle < 1 Then
    .AddItem "Cycle Over"
    End If

    If alarm < 1 Then
    .AddItem "Alarm"
    End If

    If keycard < 2 Then
    .AddItem "KeyCard"
    End If

    If door < 2 Then
    .AddItem "Door Open/Close"
    End If

End With

'disable ComboBox after use
ComboBox1.Enabled = False

End Sub
```

Note that we have to disable the ComboBox after selection, because this incrementing math won't work if someone goes back to a ComboBox and reselects more items.

If you want to write it without having to fill the boxes in a predetermined order, then it's going to be really difficult without using Classes. Here's a link on how to use them if you're interested: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/classes.aspx